# extracting multiple .gz files, and printing the name of the extracted file

Tags: linux, gzip, tee

I would think this is easy but I'm blocking…

I have a directory with a series of log files (from minecraft server…):

```
2014-09-28-1.log.gz
2014-09-29-1.log.gz
2014-09-30-1.log.gz
2014-10-01-1.log.gz
2014-10-02-1.log.gz
latest.log
```

I would like to extract the date and time when users logged in. However, when I do

```
gzcat *.gz | grep 'logged in'
```

I get an output like this:

```
[19:26:03] [Server thread/INFO]: Foo[/ip address] logged in with entity id 193955 at (location)
[18:26:08] [Server thread/INFO]: Baz[/ip address] logged in with entity id 194873 at (location)
[01:16:38] [Server thread/INFO]: User[/ip address] logged in with entity id 198895 at (location)
```

etc.

Unfortunately, while I get the time stamp, I don't get the date. Ideally the output would be

```
2014-10-03 19:26:03 Foo logged in
2014-10-04 18:26:08 Baz logged in
2014-10-05 01:16:38 User logged in
```

I recognize I might need and `awk` script to get to that "ideal" output. But is there a shorthand (non awk) solution to get just the date interspersed with the listing?  Something like this:

```
2014-10-03-1.log.gz
[19:26:03] [Server thread/INFO]: Foo[/ip address] logged in with entity id 193955 at (location)
2014-10-04-1.log.gz
[18:26:08] [Server thread/INFO]: Baz[/ip address] logged in with entity id 194873 at (location)
2014-10-05-1.log.gz
[01:16:38] [Server thread/INFO]: User[/ip address] logged in with entity id 198895 at (location)
```

(i.e. the name of the file before the grepped bits inside each file) would already be very helpful.

Note there are typically many other entries in each log file - there can be multiple logins, and other messages (which I am not interested in today).

In the shortest form, my question becomes:

> Can I use `gzcat` in a way that it prints the name of every zip file before passing the contents of that zip file to `grep` for further processing?

I *could* write a script to do the whole thing; but I'm looking for something cleverer (I was wondering whether `tee` might be used to print file name to `stderr` as well as passing as argument to `grep`, perhaps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this `gzcat` provided by `gzip` package? On my openSUSE GNU/Linux machine, the binary is called `zcat`. If `gzip` is indeed installed on your machine, then you should also have another binary called [`zgrep`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gzip.git/tree/zgrep.in), which is just a shell script that un-compresses files to `stdout` and invokes `grep`.

`zgrep` accepts (almost) the same set of arguments as `grep`. So you could do this:

> $ zgrep -H 'logged in' *.gz`

This will return output in this format:

> 2014-10-03-1.log.gz:[19:26:03] [Server thread/INFO]: Foo[/ip address] logged in with entity id 193955 at (location)

You could may be replace `.gz:` with just a whitespace  using either `tr` or `sed` to get  something close to your *ideal output*.

Comment: This does the job very nicely. Thank you! I didn't realize there was a command that combined unzip and grep, and allowed me to include the file name as part of the output - brilliant. Congratulations on your first accepted answer, too!